# Spark, ADAM and Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Trying to attempt genomic analysis using ADAM and Zeppelin.  I'm not sure if I'm doing this right but running into below issue.

```
%dep
z.reset()
z.addRepo("Spark Packages Repo").url("http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven")
z.load("com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0")   
z.load("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35")  
z.load("org.bdgenomics.adam:adam-core_2.10:0.20.0")
z.load("org.bdgenomics.adam:adam-cli_2.10:0.20.0")
z.load("org.bdgenomics.adam:adam-apis_2.10:0.20.0")

%spark

import org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext._
import org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext
import org.bdgenomics.adam.projections.{ AlignmentRecordField, Projection }
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext
import org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext._
import org.bdgenomics.adam.projections.Projection
import org.bdgenomics.adam.projections.AlignmentRecordField
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.bdgenomics.formats.avro.Genotype
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.bdgenomics.formats.avro._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{ Vector => MLVector, Vectors }
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{ KMeans, KMeansModel }

val ac = new ADAMContext(sc)
```

and I get the following output with a error

```
import org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext._
import org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext
import org.bdgenomics.adam.projections.{AlignmentRecordField, Projection}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext
import org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext._
import org.bdgenomics.adam.projections.Projection
import org.bdgenomics.adam.projections.AlignmentRecordField
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.bdgenomics.formats.avro.Genotype
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.bdgenomics.formats.avro._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector=>MLVector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
res7: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@62ec8142
<console>:188: error: constructor ADAMContext in class ADAMContext cannot be accessed in class $iwC
              new ADAMContext(sc)
```

Any idea where to look?  Am I missing any dependencies?
              ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According file [ADAMContext.scala](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam/blob/maint_2.10-0.20.0/adam-core/src/main/scala/org/bdgenomics/adam/rdd/ADAMContext.scala) in the version you use. The constructor is private.

```
class ADAMContext private (@transient val sc: SparkContext) 
    extends Serializable with Logging {
    ...
}
```

You can instead use like this.

```
import org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext._

val adamContext: ADAMContext = z.sc
```

It will use the implicit conversion in object ADAMContext

```
object ADAMContext {
    implicit def sparkContextToADAMContext(sc: SparkContext): ADAMContext = 
        new ADAMContext(sc)
}
```

Comment: I tried that and the object seems to be null `%spark 

val ac: ADAMContext = sc   
ac: org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext = null`

Answer (score 0):

It did work without using Z reference!!

```
val ac:ADAMContext  = sc
val genotypes: RDD[Genotype] = ac.loadGenotypes("/tmp/ADAM2").rdd
```

Output

```
ac: org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext = org.bdgenomics.adam.rdd.ADAMContext@2c60ef7e

genotypes: 
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.bdgenomics.formats.avro.Genotype] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at ADAMContext.scala:207
```

I had tried doing this at the adam-shell prompt and I don't recall having to use implicit conversion. It was using the 0.19 version of ADAM though.